# can't deploy rails app since upgrade to Capistrano3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I have upgraded to Capistrano3 and followed the steps in the capistrano3 documentation but still get the error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/deploy`

I am sure that I am using Capistrano 3; here is my config/deploy.rb: http://pastie.org/9483501

full log : http://pastie.org/9483504

Comment: show us your `Capfile`

Comment: Capfile : http://pastie.org/9484086

Comment: Based on the full log and the error message: is the `deploy.rb` file really on this path `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Deploy UAT/workspace/api/config/deploy.rb`?

Comment: yes, I just checked, and it is there

Answer (score 0):

The [uprade docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/) say:

> We recommend to capify the project from scratch and move definitions
>   from old to new configs then.
>
> ```
> mkdir old_cap
>     mv Capfile old_cap
>     mv config/deploy.rb old_cap
>     mv config/deploy/ old_cap # --> only for multistage setups
> cap install
> ```

I did this, got my new capfiles, and then followed the [preparing your application doc](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/) to set everything up again with the new v3 syntax, and it all worked.